# BigQuery maximum content in view

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to create a view which query more than 600 tables, BigQuery was running for a long time and response is :
BigQuery error in mk operation: Backend Error.

the query itself is like:
'select col1,col2,col3 from t1,t2,t3......t600'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the operation is timing out. The limit here is whether validating the view query can be completed within the deadline limits for a single synchronous request like view creation. This many tables may just be too many.

A potential work-around might be to shard this view: create smaller view tables, then a single view of the set of smaller views.

An alternate solution would be to explore your data layout. Perhaps you don't need 600 tables to hold your data? The BigQuery team announced at GCP Next 2016 that table partitioning by date will be coming soon, so if you are sharding your tables by day and need to reference years of data, then there will be a single-table solution for you soon.